# Software RAID 1 does not extend on two new additional drives

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-raid, mdadm, raid1

I added two new devices two my software RAID 1 system. They are recognized by mdadm but I can't use the addition space.

Here is how I proceed:

1. I added the two new disk to my PC and created on each an ext4 partition
2. I added the partitions as hotspare to the RAID 1

   ```
   mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdX1
   mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdY1
   ```
3. then I grow the raid with backup file

   ```
   mdadm --grow --raid-devices=4 /dev/md0 --backup-file=/tmp/md0.bak
   ```
4. and try to extend the disk after a disk check

   ```
   fsck.ext4 -f /dev/md0
   resize2fs /dev/md0
   ```

   resize2fs returns:

   > The filesystem is already * blocks long. Nothing to do!

**What went wrong here?**

---

Here some more system details:

```
uname -a
Linux server 3.8.0-44-generic #66~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:01:04 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Wed Oct 16 11:50:14 2013
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 2930134016 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2930134016 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue May 12 17:55:36 2015
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : server:md0
           UUID : 4993aaa0:cc999f7a:c3f6e0fb:1a23bbb7
         Events : 755

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       65        0      active sync   /dev/sde1
       1       8       81        1      active sync   /dev/sdf1
       3       8       17        2      active sync   /dev/sdX1
       2       8        1        3      active sync   /dev/sdY1

cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
[...]
ARRAY /dev/md/md0 level=raid1 num-devices=4 metadata=1.2 name=server:md0 UUID=4993aaa0:cc999f7a:c3f6e0fb:1a23bbb7
   devices=/dev/sde1,/dev/sdf1,/dev/sdX1,/dev/sdY1
```

Comment: Reading more about RAID1, it looks like I have now 4 times mirrored the same informations. Is there not a way to extend the RAID1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RAID1 doesn't work that way.  When you added those two new partitions to your array, you added two more *copies* of the data.  You added *redundancy*, not *capacity*.

At this point you ought to look into either RAID5, which will gain you disk capacity x (number of disks - 1), or something like RAIDZ or btrfs.

Comment: "You added redundancy, not capacity." Thats what I learned now!

Comment: Do you still want to add capacity?

Comment: Yes I want to add capacity! My plan is to remove 3 of the drives from the array and use them to build a RAID5. Then copy all the data and add the fourth drive...